# How can I assign an EventListener to a Path in javafx?

Tags: javafx, event-handling

I have this piece of code which doesn't work correctly.
I want to set a listener for when a user clicks inside the square, yet
neither the pop-up nor the message "clicked" are displayed when I click
inside the square.

What am I missing?

This method is inside the Coords class.

```
public static void drawMyShape(final GraphicsContext ctx) {
    Path path = new Path();
    MoveTo mT = new MoveTo();
    LineTo lT[] = new LineTo[4];


    mT.setX(200.0);
    mT.setY(200.0);
    lT[0] = new LineTo(400.0, 200.0);
    lT[1] = new LineTo(400.0, 400.0);
    lT[2] = new LineTo(200.0, 400.0);
    lT[3] = new LineTo(200.0, 200.0);
    path.setStroke(Color.BEIGE);
    path.getElements().addAll(mT, lT[0], lT[1], lT[2], lT[3]);

    path.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            final Stage dialog = new Stage();
            dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            dialog.initOwner(Main.prim_stage);
            VBox box = new VBox(20);
            box.getChildren().add(new Text("Hey"));
            Scene s = new Scene(box, 300, 200);
            dialog.setScene(s);
            dialog.show();
            System.out.println("Clicked");
        }
    });

    ctx.setLineWidth(4.0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mT.getX(), mT.getY());
    for (int i = 0; i < lT.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(lT[i].getX(), lT[i].getY());
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

EDITED ON SUGGESTION by users.

So his is the main program:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static Pane root;
    private static Canvas main_canvas;
    private static GraphicsContext ctx;
    private static Rectangle2D bounds;
    private static Scene scene;
    public static Stage prim_stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Switzerland Advertising");
        initElements(primaryStage);
        Coords.drawMyShape(ctx);
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println("Launched");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Everything is instanciated inside the following function, which works correctly and displays a full screen application with a canvas and a square drawn into it (image at the bottom).

```
private void initElements(final Stage primaryStage) {
    prim_stage = primaryStage;
    // ----------------------------------------
    bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    double w = bounds.getWidth();
    double h = bounds.getHeight();
    // ----------------------------------------
    // init elements of scene
    root = new Pane();
    main_canvas = new Canvas(w, h);
    // ----------------------------------------
    // init scene elements
    scene = new Scene(root, w, h);
    primaryStage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
    primaryStage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
    primaryStage.setWidth(w);
    primaryStage.setHeight(h);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    // ----------------------------------------
    ctx = main_canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    // set elements in main pane
    root.getChildren().add(main_canvas);
    // ----------------------------------------
}
```

So how can I make the pop-up window appear whenever I click inside the region drawn on the canvas?
[This is the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/341B7.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question. This makes it easier for people to debug and offer a solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is just a local variabl within your method. It has to be attached to the scene graph in order to get events. But when you attach it to the scene graph, drawing the same path on a canvas also does not make much sense.

Comment: Attaching it to the root and deleting the canvas kind of does what I want. Yet id displays the pop-up when I click on the lines of the square, not when I click inside the square. How can I do that?

Comment: Fill the interior of the path with some non-transparent color. (The one that you have attached the mouse listener to.)

Comment: Or call `path.setPickOnBounds(true)`